# MVC5 Html.BeginForm won't post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Help. I don't know how to resolve this issue. I'm just looking for the submit button to go to the controller and action method but I get Error 404 - The resource cannot be found.

Code is below

My cshtml:

```
@model TS_MVC.Models.LoginPage
@using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateUser", "Login", FormMethod.Post)) {
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginForm.Email, new { @size = "40", @maxlength = "80" })
</ br>
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.LoginForm.Password, new { @maxlength = "15" })
</ br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
}
```

My LoginController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateUser(LoginPage user) {
...
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your question at hand, but the HTML element should be written `<br>` or `<br/>`.

Comment: For such a simple page, why Are your `Email` and `Password` properties on a sub-object? Is your Controller in a different MVC Area?

Comment: Yeah Mike, I was just quickly typing it out - my bad

Comment: Krillgar, So I've removed the model and now just have: @using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateUser", "Login", FormMethod.Post)) { But this isn't posting back to LoginController and it's ValidateUser method